# ffmpeg mapping all tracks but only the best video track

Tags: ffmpeg

I struggle to understand the map documentation.

The streams I am inputting have multiple tracks for video (different quality streams), some have subtitles and some have several audio tracks.

What I would like to do is map only the best video stream, which is the equivalent of not having the map parameter entered at all, but keep all other streams (if they exist) intact.

Does anyone know how I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want a one-size-fits-all command that keeps all streams in a single input stream intact, apart from the video tracks where I want to keep only the best quality one.

Comment: Unfortunately, not possible. Best streams are only chosen in absence of any maps.

Comment: You can remove unwanted streams. That wont work? `ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -map -0:2 -c copy output ` - will remove stream 0:2